# Как создать POST на JSOUP если тип запроса XML

Tags: android, xml, post, jsoup

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при нажатии кнопки на сайте передается `post` запрос с типом XML.

Как создать этот запрос на Android через JSOUP?

Также как и HTML POST?

Или тут какие то свои подводные камни? В интернете информацию не нашел.

при нажатии <kbd>F12</kbd> в мозиле появляется :
метод POST, тип XML
хедеры :

```
POST /argus/block/send-receive-updates HTTP/1.1
Host: URL
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: URL
Content-Length: 752
Cookie: JSESSIONID; 
ice.sessions=sessionid
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

и собственно значений во вкладке параметры:

```
ice.submit.partial=true
ice.event.target=mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id145
ice.event.captured=mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144
ice.event.type=onclick
ice.event.alt=false
ice.event.ctrl=false
ice.event.shift=false
ice.event.meta=false
ice.event.x=71             **это судя по всему координаты х,у места нажатия кнопки** 
ice.event.y=113
ice.event.left=true
ice.event.right=false
mainform=mainform
icefacesCssUpdates
javax.faces.ViewState=1
javax.faces.RenderKitId=ICEfacesRenderKit
mainform:mainform:queryTree_idta
mainform:mainform:queryTree_idtn
mainform:j_id137Expanded
mainform:j_id137ClickedNodeName
mainform:procSearch
mainform:_idcl=mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144
ice.session=TVi-cz23Of9XMYp0dwMjcw   **не знаю откуда это берется**
ice.view=1
ice.focus=mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144   
rand=0.7699530793865863     **и это тоже**
```

Comment: jsoup же для парсинга вэб страниц библиотека.

Comment: @Андроид Андроид ну вот я ее и использовал) после нажатия этой кнопки появляется html таблица, которую мне и надо спарсить

Comment: метод post, тип xml

Comment: А, всё, понял. Надо думать)

Comment: То есть по идее надо сымитировать клик этой кнопки, а только потом парсить?

Comment: @Андроид Андроид оно самое, правда в отличии от логина на сайте во вкладке параметры (читай data) куча значений, несколько из них разные каждую сессию, где их брать непонятно

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась! 
На оригинальном стаке мне сказали, что JSOUP не подходит для обработки javascript
Поэтому я решил воспользоваться WebView